# Update UI From another thread c++ Windows Form app

Tags: c++, multithreading, user-interface, windows-forms-designer

I would like to update ui thread from a thread I created with this function :

```
CreateThread
```

Here is my code

```
[STAThread]
void Main(array<String^>^ args) {
Application::EnableVisualStyles();
Application::SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);

gRecvSockThread = CreateThread(NULL, 0, recvSocket, NULL, 0, NULL);

MyApp::MyForm form;
Application::Run(%form);
}

DWORD WINAPI recvSocket(void *arg) {

char recvbuf[8];
RtlZeroMemory(recvbuf, 8);
while (gSocket->getStateSocket() != -1) {
    int iResult = recv(gSocket->getSocketFD(), recvbuf, 8, MSG_WAITALL);
    if (iResult > 0) {
        if (strcmp("accepted", recvbuf) == 0) {
            //updateUIValidated(); //here I would like to access a label and make it visible for example..
        }
        else {
            //updateUIRejected();
        }
    }

}
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Can you elaborate about the particular problems you face? Race conditions?

Comment: recvSocket is a function executed from a thread. From this function I would like to access ui thread as you can see after the strcmp I would like to updateUI but I don't have access to the button of my form...

Comment: You need to make some public function in your form to make it accessible.

Comment: Mallocate/new your buffer array/srtuct/object, PostMessage() it to the form, in event-hander method, render it to your visual thingy component and then free/delete it.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I tried public methods still not accessible... It says : identifier updateUIValidated is undefined

Comment: Do you provide a header to access your form class?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I did not understand what do you mean.
In my post this my class MyForm.cpp I have a header MyForm.h

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved by using `System::Threading;` instead of `CreateThread` and create delegate attribute.
Bind this attribute with the method that will update the UI :

```
delegateUpdateUI = gcnew UpdateUI(this, &MyForm::UpdateUIMethod);
```

And then on my thread I call :

```
Invoke(delegateAcceptedUI);
```

And finish :)